# How can I pull records for a full month AFTER a specific date?

Tags: postgresql

I have a list of employees and their hire dates. I need to pull revenue records for their first 3 months on the job. For example, if someone is hired on August 6 2018, I need to pull their revenue records for September, October, and November 2018.

I really just need the "where" statement to find the correct dates.

Let's call the tables: bookings, employees
columns: hired_at, booked_at

I originally thought it was first 3 months from hire date, and I used
where bookings.booked_at <= dateadd(month, 3, employees.hire_date)

Upon finding out that I need the 3 months FOLLOWING the hire date, I'm not sure how to write this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use INTERVAL, dateadd isn't supported by PostgreSQL

<= employees.hire_date - Interval '3 months'

You can check the documentation in the following link

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/functions-datetime.html

Comment: my dateadd function is working. What I need is the entire revenue from Sept 1 - Sept 30, Oct 1 - Oct 31, and Nov 1 - Nov 30. When I use interval, for 3 months, it calculates from Aug 6 - Oct 6. I need the revenue to start counting on Day 1 of the next month and continue for 3 full months

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE booked_at >= date_trunc('month', hired_at + interval '1 month')
  AND booked_at < date_trunc('month', hired_at + interval '3 month')
```

where `date_trunc('month', ...)` always gives you the 1st of the month.